# TFS 2010 suddenly thinks ALL changesets need to be merged again

Tags: version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

We have the standard basic TFS 2010 branches setup - Dev <-> Main <-> Release.

We've merged up and down the chain multiple times over the past several months with no issues.

A couple of weeks ago we merged Main -> Release and deployed a new version of software.
As far as we know there were no issues with the merge and the new version in Release seems fine.

Today we were preparing to merge another set of changes from Main to Release and when we brought up the window to see what changesets were available to merge - surprisingly TFS listed ALL changes from the beginning of the application!

Is there some common/stupid thing we could have done so that TFS thinks the Release branch is no longer current or needs to have ALL changesets re-merged from Main to Release?

The issue is not specific to any developer's machine.

What's also strange is I can do View History on the Release branch, and I see all the changesets just fine - so I know Release is good.

The only thing out of the ordinary in the changes going from Main to Release are changes to the solution and project files where we upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and changed the target framework to 4.5.  When we went from Dev to Main with these changes however, it didn't cause any kind of problem like this.  It just updated the modified sln, proj, etc files.

Has anyone ever ran across something like this?

Comment: Did someone re-parent the branch? Rename either two branches? Move the branch? Delete the merge relationship? Do a baseless merge from dev directly to main (or the other way around)? What does your Branch Visualization look like when you view it?

Comment: Too see your branch relationships, check out the following lab exercise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_branchingandmerging_topic3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears this was caused by a "resurrected" file that had previously been deleted (and another file created using the same name).

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118265/team-foundation-server-previously-merged-changesets-reappear-in-merge-wizard)